# Can't pass data through segue. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory, segue

I cannot pass variables through ViewControllers, even though I honestly think I have done all the necessities.

*Game3ViewController:*

```
class Game3ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
var START = 1

var zombieMarkersCenters: [[Double]] = Array(repeating:Array(repeating:0, count:2), count:10)

var zombieHealth: [Int] = Array(repeating:100, count:10)

var HP = 100

var bullets = [0,0]

/* ... REST OF THE CODE */

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
/* here I assign values to the variables */
}

/* ... REST OF THE CODE */

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "goToBackpack"
    {
        let Backpack4 = segue.destination as! Backpack4ViewController

        Backpack4.zombieMarkersCentersBackpack = zombieMarkersCenters
        Backpack4.bulletsBackpack = bullets
        Backpack4.STARTBackpack = START
        Backpack4.zombieHealthBackpack = zombieHealth
    }
}

/* ACTIONS */

@IBAction func openBackpack(_ sender: Any)
{   
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToBackpack", sender: self)

    timer.invalidate()
}
```

*Backpack4ViewController:*

```
class Backpack4ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var zombieMarkersCentersBackpack = [[Double]]()
    var bulletsBackpack = [Int]()
    var STARTBackpack = Int()
    var zombieHealthBackpack = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("WORKS?: ", bulletsBackpack, STARTBackpack, zombieHealthBackpack)

    /* ... REST OF THE CODE */
```

And the print results with: [] 0 [], so I guess data passage has never happened. What should I do?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you stepped through your code and used breakpoints? When you use the debugger and step through the code are you sure that all the correct methods are called and all the variables are set correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this is not a method that will ever be called:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

That's pointless; it won't be called, and your code will never run.

You need to write this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

Now your method will be called.

Comment: Works all beautifully now. Thanks!